# Magmi error with redis

Tags: php, magento, redis, server, magmi

I am trying to use a magmi module for masive import on a magento.
But on the server i am warking is install rediss session and return this error
[Image error](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BycMjc_qF_QrWjVTODNWQXRBUFE/view?usp=sharing)
Please if someone can help me

Comment: Welcome to SO.So we can help you, can you post the code to show us what you have tried so far?

Comment: I haved installed a magmi ( https://sourceforge.net/projects/magmi/) on a server, and when i was to use it, the error produce. On a local server i did not have any problem and the unic difference is the redis session. The code is of the magmi i dont write any code

Comment: How can I import products images for multi-store, may i know csv header columns